# Name files after split command

Tags: bash, regex, split

there is a large file I split in bash. I am using

```
split -l 20000 -d "job1" "job1"
```

where job 1 is the input file -  how can I change the naming of the output so that it produces 
job1_1,job1_2,gob1_3...,job1_12.....

is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30525185/1030675

Comment: Please don't cross-post your questions.

Comment: it wasnt me realyy shagr

Comment: I hope `gob1_3` is a typo and you mean `job1_3`

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Your command

```
split -l 20000 -d "job1" "job1"
```

puts 20000 lines per output file with a numeric suffix. The input is `job1` and the **output prefix** is `job1`.

Therefore change the output prefix from `job1` to `job1_`

---

Your command:

```
split -l 20000 -d job1 job1_
```

Avoid the leading zero:

```
split -l 20000 -d job1 job1_; rename 's/_0{1,}([0-9]+)/_$1/' job1_*
```

Avoid the leading zero and start the numeric suffix with `1`:

```
split -l 20000 --numeric-suffixes=1 job1 job1_; rename 's/_0{1,}([0-9]+)/_$1/' job1_*
```

---

Example 1:

```
% split -l 20000 -d job1 job1_
% ls -og job1*                
-rw-rw-r-- 1 10000000 Mai 29 16:03 job1
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1540000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_00
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1540000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_01
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1540000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_02
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1540000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_03
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1540000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_04
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1540000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_05
-rw-rw-r-- 1   760000 Mai 29 16:09 job1_06
```

Example 2:

```
% split -l 10000 -d job1 job1_; rename 's/_0{1,}([0-9]+)/_$1/' job1_*
% ls -og job1*                                                       
-rw-rw-r-- 1 10000000 Mai 29 16:03 job1
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_0
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_1
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_10
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_11
-rw-rw-r-- 1   760000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_12
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_2
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_3
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_4
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_5
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_6
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_7
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_8
-rw-rw-r-- 1   770000 Mai 29 16:23 job1_9
```

from `man split`

```
SYNOPSIS
       split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]

-d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]
              use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic; FROM changes the start value (default 0)

-l, --lines=NUMBER
              put NUMBER lines per output file
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is to just add underscore then:

> split -l 20000 -d "job1" "job1_"